# Calculate $\int_{S^{n-1}} x_1x_2 dS$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, smooth-manifolds, spheres

How do I calculate $\int_{S^{n-1}} x_1x_2 dS$ (where $S^{n-1}$ is the $n-1$ dimensional sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$)? 
At the first part of the question I needed to calculate $I=\int_{S^{n-1}} x_1^2$ and to do that I just used symmetry, to get $nI = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \int_{S^{n-1}} x_i^2 = \int_{S^{n-1}} 1$, but what do I do here? I am allowed to write the answer in terms of $\int_{S^{n-1}}1$. Thanks!

Comment: Think symmetry again.

Comment: @UmbertoP I tried to consider the integral of $(x_1+...+x_n)^2$. If I knew how to calculate it, that will finish the question, but I am not sure how to find it's value (or if it is the right way to go).

Comment: As an example, can you use symmetry to evaluate $\int_{S^2} x \, dS$?

Comment: @UmbertoP Oh wait, is it just 0 by symmetry? because we can take the parts of the sphere where x1>0, x2>0 and x1<0, x2<0 and by symmetry they give the same surface area, say S, and the parts where x1>0, x2<0 and x1<0, x2>0 cancel the previous ones. Is it correct?

Comment: That's right!$\mbox{}$

Answer (score 2):

$\displaystyle\int_{S^{n-1}}x_1x_2 \, dS = 0$ by the change of variables formula. If you make the change of variables $(x_1, \dots, x_n) \mapsto (-x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)$, the integrand picks up a $-$sign, while the region of integration stays the same.